# In ruby, how do I get the subject, issuer etc. after creating an OpenSSL PKCS12 object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, pkcs#12

If I use

```
c = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new data
```

is there something like c.subject or s.expiry to get these attributes?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: Yes- is it in there? I can't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PKCS#12 is a container format that collects keys and certificates and stores them in a possibly encrypted format. Most of the time, the file is encrypted, so you would "load" the PKCS12 object like this:

```
p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(data, "password")
```

If the password was correct, you will now have access to the key and certificate:

```
key = p12.key
cert = p12.certificate
```

With the certificate, you can now access the subject and expiry using the methods of [OpenSSL::X509::Certificate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html). Note that the expiry is accessed by `#not_after'.