# How can I safely read a PKCS12 and pass it to an object in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ssl, encoding, openssl, pkcs#12

I'm currently using the google api client gem to communicate with the google apis. It uses PKCS12 to authenticate with these services and uses OpenSSL::PKCS12.new

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS12.html

However when I read the file with File.read and try to pass the string around I get String has a null byte error. How can I avoid this and make sure it is still DER encoded for the PKCS12 class?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon, could you post the code that is failing?

Answer (score 6):

```
require 'openssl'

p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read('/path/to/p12'), "pass_phrase")
key = p12.key
certificate = p12.certificate
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out shortly after I posted the bounty on this question. 
The question, [In ruby, how do I get the subject, issuer etc. after creating an OpenSSL PKCS12 object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646832/in-ruby-how-do-i-get-the-subject-issuer-etc-after-creating-an-openssl-pkcs12) was useful in coming up with this solution.

[OpenSSL::PKCS12::new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS12.html#method-c-new) will throw an exception is a String isn't a valid DER encoded string or the password is incorrect.

Here is the validator I wrote for my model,

```
def valid_pkcs12_file
  begin
    test = OpenSSL::PKCS12::new(pkcs12_file.read, password)
  rescue Exception => e
    Rails.logger.warn "pkcs12 error #{e.message}"
    errors.add(:pkcs12_file, 'invalid pkcs12 file or password')
  ensure
    pkcs12_file.rewind
  end
end
```

If anyone has a more elegant approach I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12` instead of `OpenSSL::PKCS12.new`. It will return a `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` instance.

`load_from_pkcs12` will raise `ArgumentError: Invalid keyfile or passphrase` if the file is not valid or the passphrase is wrong.

From the [README](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client):

```
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12('client.p12', 'notasecret')
# and so on
```

(Tested with ruby-2.1.0)

Comment: How would you check validity of the file using that method?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon I have updated my answer. Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks, but I think I will use the answer I suggested to avoid importing another gem.

Comment: I used the Google-Gem because the original question mentions this. Of course, if you're not using the Google-API-Client gem, it makes no sense using it...